# Button for Toast NotificationsExtensions not appearing

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, toast

This is my first time implementing a *Toast* notification, but I have a problem with buttons:

[image]

I am creating the Toast notification using `NotificationsExtensions`:

```
ToastContent tc = new ToastContent()
        {
            Visual = new ToastVisual()
            {
                TitleText = new ToastText() { Text = "Quick Save" },
                BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText() { Text = "Type below the info that you wanna save and press enter" }
            },
            Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
            {
                Inputs =
                {
                    new ToastTextBox(nameBox)
                    {
                        PlaceholderContent = "type here"
                    }
                },

                Buttons =
                {
                    new ToastButton("save", "save")
                    {
                        TextBoxId = nameBox
                    }
                }
            },
                Duration = ToastDuration.Short
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot add `ImageUri` for your button

```
ToastContent tc = new ToastContent()
{
    Visual = new ToastVisual()
    {
        TitleText = new ToastText()
        {
            Text = "Quick Save"
        },
        BodyTextLine1 = new ToastText()
        {
            Text = "Type below the info that you wanna save and press enter"
        }
    },

    Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
    {
        Inputs =
        {
            new ToastTextBox("nameBox")
            {
                PlaceholderContent = "type here"
            }
        },

        Buttons =
        {
            new ToastButton("save", "save")
            {
                TextBoxId = "nameBox",
                ImageUri = "Assets/check.png"
            }
        }
    }
};

var text = tc.GetContent();
var xml = tc.GetXml();
var toast = new ToastNotification(xml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

[image]

Comment: Why the ImageUri is important? And if i wanna a real button?

Comment: @HeribertoFilho design from microsoft.

Comment: When you're using the quick reply style button, an image is required.

If you want normal buttons below the text box, don't specify the TextBoxId property on your ToastButton, and it'll appear below your text box as a normal button, displaying text.